# Accessing a main class variable through a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm using a separate class to construct a message box with "Don't show again" checkBox.

Everything runs fine, but i want to add a different variable to each messagebox object.

So I took the original class, and added an argument

```
static public DialogResult ShowDialog(string title, string largeHeading, string smallExplanation,
        string leftButton, string rightButton, Image iconSet, int variavelcaixa)
```

Where the ´int variavelcaixa´ is a variable of the type int, that each messagebox object will have.

For example i would create a message box in the main class like the following:

```
MsgBoxCheck.MessageBox dlg = new MsgBoxCheck.MessageBox();
                string icone = "C:\\warning.png";
                DialogResult result = BetterDialog.ShowDialog("Alert",
      "Warning message 1",
      "some consequences in a string",
      "Do action button", "Cancel button", System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(icone), variableofthismessagebox);
```

Where variableofthismessagebox will be different on each messagebox object.

Problem: How can I change the value of variableofthismessagebox trough the variavelcaixa in the secondary class, when the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword.

```
static public DialogResult ShowDialog(string title, string largeHeading, string smallExplanation, string leftButton, string rightButton, Image iconSet, ref int variavelcaixa)
```

---

```
DialogResult result = BetterDialog.ShowDialog("Alert",
  "Warning message 1",
  "some consequences in a string",
  "Do action button", "Cancel button", System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(icone),
   ref variableofthismessagebox);
```

`ref` will make `variavelcaixa` point to the variable `variableofthismessagebox` in your main class.

More info: [Ref Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ref)

Comment: wow, but if that's the case, why don't we use ref for the other arguments, like strings and images?

Comment: Data types (`string`s, `int`s, etc) are passed by _value_, and not _reference_ by default. (Where as reference types, such as `Image`, have their properties passed by reference) This means if you pass an `int` with the value of `0`, and you modify it in a method, it will not change in the calling code. Using the `ref` keyword tells it to point to the actual reference of the `int`. Normally you are either using reference types, or using a data type, but not needing to modify it in the called method.

Comment: Hmm it was not that, I think that's because i'm trying to change the value of the variable on the checkbox click event. Because it's a event separated from the constructor, i have to state ´variavelcaixa´ as public at the start of the class, or it wont recognize it in the event. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm using exactly the following class http://www.dotnetperls.com/customized-dialog

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I'll write something in the morning.